# Exclude application from accessibility tools

Tags: c++, windows, accessibility-api

Our software uses standard `IAccessible` interfaces and we can use tool `INSPECT` visualize all supported areas in our windows.

Now we have a customer, that doesn't use any accessibility tools at all. But we see random crashes when a call is mode through the `IAccessible` interface for an object, that is already destroyed. We can see this in crash dumps (full dumps), we received from the customer.

Using several test tools for the accessibility doesn't cause any crashes in our software. So we are unable to repro the issue.

We suppose that some software tries to use the `IAccessible` interfaces and has a bug.

Is there a way to exclude my software (i.e. by a registry key) so that the `IAccessible` objects are not created and delivered to another software like the inspect tool.

Comment: Are you talking about IAccessible provided by controls in comctl32 etc?

Comment: Exactly that is what I am talking about. Should I add some more information to clarify this?

Comment: Yes, is it ListView etc. And your customer must be running something that uses the interface...